# TypeError: cannot read property of undefined (reading 'map') while fetching from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js

I am working on a full stack blog site project where I have created an API for back-end and its working fine and I am getting posts from it but when I try to iterate it using map it throws me error
`Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`, I am using NextJS for my front-end.

**Code**

```
const Blogs = ({ blogs }) => {
  return (
    <div className='all-blogs'>
      {blogs.map((blog) => (
        <div className='single-blog' key={blog._id}>
          <h1>{blog.title}</h1>
          <p>{blog.text}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch(
    'https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts'
  )
  const blogs = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      blogs,
    },
  }
}
```

endpoint I am fetching: `https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts`

[[image: API fetch result on right][1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that `blogs`, as a prop value, is undefined until the asynchronous logic defines and populates it. You can handle this a couple ways.

1. Provide a default prop value.

   ```
   const Blogs = ({ blogs = [] }) => {
     return (
       <div className='all-blogs'>
         {blogs.map((blog) => (
           <div className='single-blog' key={blog._id}>
             <h1>{blog.title}</h1>
             <p>{blog.text}</p>
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```
2. Provide a fallback value to map from.

   ```
   const Blogs = ({ blogs }) => {
     return (
       <div className='all-blogs'>
         {(blogs ?? []).map((blog) => (
           <div className='single-blog' key={blog._id}>
             <h1>{blog.title}</h1>
             <p>{blog.text}</p>
           </div>
         ))}
       </div>
     )
   }
   ```

Note that in the event the GET requests fails (i.e. the `fetch` returns a rejected Promise) or any other exception is thrown while processing the request/response, then you will want to guard this by using a `try/catch`. Either provide valid, defined prop values to the page, or return that an error occurred or that the page content was unable to be found.

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  let blogs = [];
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://ed-blog-api.herokuapp.com/api/posts');
    blogs = await res.json();
  } catch(error) {
    // handle error, logging, etc...
    // maybe optionally returning `notFound: true` as a 404
  }
  return {
    props: {
      blogs,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: But the fetch is inside `getStaticProps`, props always should be defined unless the fetch thows an error, your argument right only if fetch is declared inside function component.

Comment: @ChemiAdel I didn't say `props` was undefined, that's not really possible in React. I said the `blogs` prop value is undefined. In other words, a value hasn't been assigned to it yet.

Comment: @ChemiAdel has a point.  `blogs` will only be `undefined` inside `Blog` if the request fails inside `getStaticProps` (note that the error is happening on the server when Next.js is pre-rendering the page). A better solution here is to handle the API call properly in `getStaticProps`.

Comment: @juliomalves I don't disagree with your comment, added a bit of clarification.